# Is it possible to run a Python script in Paperspace without keeping the editor open in the Internet browser?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, neural-network

[image]

This is my paperspace window.

My script is running for hours. As a result, I have to keep my browser and laptop open.

Is it possible to run a Python script in Paperspace without keeping the editor open in the Internet browser?